# DateFormat format ROC year between JDK 1.6 and 1.7

Tags: java, simpledateformat

"java.text.SimpleDateFormat" doesn't support the ROC year, so I write a class extends java.text.SimpleDateFormat.

I've defined that 'e' represents the ROC year, like 'y' represents the year.

```
TwyDateFormat format = new TwyDateFormat("eee-MM-dd- HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(new java.util.Date()); // if now is Wed Jul 10 13:53:58 CST 2013
```

It will show "102-07-10 13:53:58" in JDK 1.7, but show "02-07-10 13:53:58" in JDK 1.6.

I found that there is a little difference between JDK 1.6 and JDK 1.7, as shown below.

[JDK Source Code](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2vhcTgHt-o_MUNpYWtmZ2FNa0U/edit) (I'm sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post images....)

In JDK 1.7, pattern length is not equals 2 will be treated as 4, no matter is 'y' or 'yyy' will be treated 'yyyy'.
In JDK 1.6, pattern length is smaller than 4 will be treated as 2, which means 'yyy' will be treated 'yy'.

Is there any way to reach them same result in JDK 1.6?

Thanks all!

Comment: With 'ROC year' you mean the year according to the [Minguo calendar or Republic of China calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minguo_calendar)?

Comment: Uhm ... since *you* write the code for `eee`, why should the `SimpleDateFormat` code influence how `eee` behaves?

Comment: @mthmulders Yes, "ROC year" is what your post said.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I've write a class extends SimpleDateFormat, and replace  'e' to 'y' before the formating the date.

Answer (score 1):

I guess JodaTime could manage ROC Calendar.

[have a look](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Working_with_DateTime)

Comment: Thanks your advice! But I really want to know is there any other way to reach the same result without the third library...:Q